# Get access to pdf and other format file on local disk (like mediaGallery)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I'm developing a Chrome application where I want to do basic stuff with currently downloaded files(mostly I want to move them to a new location using an application or extension whichever is possible).

I'm able to get access to the image, audio, video file using the mediaGallery API of Chrome apps. Is there a possible way I can get access to and being able to move other format file from their current location to some other location using Chromium apps?

Answer (score 0):

You certainly read the contents of any directory that the user has given you access to. And, once the user has done this, you can retain the entry so on subsequent executions you don't have to keep asking the user to select the directory. Then, once you have a file, you can use the file API to manipulate it.

This is in principle all the media API does, except that it comes with knowledge of some built-in media directories.

Comment: when i access or read the directories using media API, it does not give me access to file other than image,video,audio files.

Is there a way we can get the access to files other than this format?
By default i am not getting access to all the files.

when i do direntry.readEntries . It seems to only show me file which are either video or  audio or image.

Can i do something which can give me access to other format files?

Comment: That sounds right to me. If you want other files, the user will have to select the directory via chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry.